# Zsh completion resource?

Tags: zsh, tab-completion

Zsh completion is a rather complex beast, and I find the man-page very difficult to read, especially it's missing (simple) examples of all the various optspec forms etc.  I haven't managed to find anything online myself yet so help would be most appreciated.

As an example here's what I'm struggling with at the moment, and the `zshcompsys` man-page doesn't offer any clarifications.  I have

```
#compdef mtt2

_arguments -s : \
    '-h' '--help' \
    '-V' '--version' \
    ':foobars:(foo bar baz)'
```

Now, when I type `mtt2 <TAB>` I'm only offered `foo`, `bar` and `baz` as completions, why not `-h`, `--help`, etc, as well?
What magic do I need to pass to `_arguments` in order to be offered all possibilities?

Comment: You need to type `mtt2 -<TAB>` if you want to see the options.

Comment: @Bertrand, yes exactly, and that's why I asked the question, I want to see *all* possible completions on `mtt2 <TAB>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start argument that you complete with dash (I mean that argument that you type to test, not `_arguments` argument). You should either look at `zstyle`, try to pass `-h` and others just like `:foobars:` or even directly use `compadd`. Examples:

1. Directly using compadd:

   ```
   #compdef test
   A=( -h --help -V --version foo bar baz )
   compadd -a A
   ```
2. Passing `-h` and others just like `:foobars:`:

   ```
   #compdef test
   A=( -h --help -V --version )
   _arguments \
       - foobars \
       ':foobars:(foo bar baz)' \
       - options \
       ":arguments:($A)"
   ```

   or

   ```
   A=( -h --help -V --version foo bar baz )
   _arguments \
       ":::($A)"
   ```
3. `zstyle` controls completion style. It is described in «COMPLETION SYSTEM CONFIGURATION» section in `man zshcompsys` and probably has an option that will enable completing of switches, but I do not know which option controls that.

Comment: Do you have an example that I can take a look at, so I stand a chance of understanding what you are saying? ;-)

Comment: I assume this means that adding descriptions to the different options (-h, -V, ...) becomes difficult, is that correct?

Comment: @Magnus, Adding descriptions with `compadd` is probably simpler, but in this examples it is not too difficult. You will face problems when you will try to provide a way to specify more then one switch and an argument at one time.

Comment: You need the `prefix-needed` style set to false to enable completing of switches without an initial -. It's common to use it with `_approximate`.